# How to power 83V UV-C germicide tube?

Tags: ac, lighting, uv, fluorescent-lamp

I'm currently working on a UV-C germicide lamp, and among the things I have to do, is to drive four 83V OSRAM 21283 G55T8/OF 55W G13 T8 Tubes. Here's a [link to the tube,](https://www.osram.com/ecat/PURITEC%20HNS%20Linear%20Lamps-PURITEC%20HNS%20Germicidal%20Lamps-Ultraviolet%20Lamps-Specialty%20Discharge%20Lamps-Entertainment%20&%20Industry/com/en/GPS01_3048998/PP_EUROPE_Europe_eCat/ZMP_4021031/) and the [datasheet.](https://www.osram.com/appsj/pdc/pdf.do?cid=GPS01_3048998&vid=PP_EUROPE_Europe_eCat&lid=EN&mpid=ZMP_4021031)

My question is, how to power each of these lights? Being that they are rated 83V as opposed to 110V or anything closer to that. Also, I'm assuming they work with AC (and I hope this isn't a stupid observation), but there's no clear indication of that. Is this correct?

I don't have much experience in terms of installing lights, but being that this qualifies as fluorescent I know at the very least it could use a ballast.

I'd like to be pointed out what has to be between the 110V AC source and each of the tubes. And I'd also like to know: Is a direct connection between the base and the source (through the driver, of course) out of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UV-C germicidal lamp is identical to a standard fluorescent lamp ...the only difference being the lack of a phosphor to convert the UV to white light.
See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp).
The link above also shows an electronic ballast (though no real design details. You should be able to use any appropriate ballast for a T8 florescent lamp of the same power.

You can get single, dual and quad ballasts, but it's preferable to go for those that support the heaters for quick and even starts ....[this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009K67XB4) is an example.

For the secondary part of your question ...YES ...the lamps need to be driven by AC. While you could build a driver that worked on DC input (say 12-24V) you need to drive the lamp with an AC signal.

For the third part of your question, the 83V is the 'on' voltage of the tube. The driver ensure that there is a higher voltage available to 'strike' the tube on each AC half cycle. While in many applications the AC freq is 50/60Hz, you can drive these lamps up to several kHz.